# Mapstrcture map a "path"

Tags: go

I had a json structure like:

```yaml
mongoCluster:
  group: some-group
  name: some-name
```

And I have made a mapping in go like:

```golang
type Config struct {
  MongoCluster  MongoCluster `mapstructure:"mongoCluster"`
}

type MongoCluster struct {
  Group string `mapstructure:"group"`
  Name string `mapstructure:"name"`
}
```

This structure have changed to:

```yaml
mongo:
  cluster:
    group: some-group
    name: some-name
```

I was thinking that I could avoid creating a `Cluster` struct and just say to `mapstructure` that my object now lives in `mongo.cluster` instead of `mongoCluster`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a full context of your intention. But I think yes you can reuse `MongoCluster` and tweak `Config` struct like the following bellow.

```
type Config struct {
   Mongo map[string]MongoCluster `mapstructure:"mongo"`
}

type MongoCluster struct {
  Group string `mapstructure:"group"`
  Name string `mapstructure:"name"`
}
```

see code example [in here](https://go.dev/play/p/Gxey9gY6ARw)